# How exactly classical electrodynamics fails to explain the Compton effect?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons

**EDIT:** This is a more precise version of an old post [Classical Theory explanation of Compton Effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/433336/classical-theory-explanation-of-compton-effect)  by someone else.

Standard textbooks explain the Compton effect using the notion of photon. It is always stated that the classical theory fails to explain the experiment. In fact, Compton in his original paper "A quantum theory of the scattering of X-rays by light elements" (1923) writes the same thing without any reference. More precisely Compton writes that according to the classical theory, the scattered radiation must have the same wave length as the incident radiation. I am looking for a proof of this statement.

So far I could find in Landau-Lifshitz textbook a proof of the above statement in two cases, *both under the assumption that the electrons are non-relativistic*: in $\S$ 78 it is proven for free electrons, and in $\S 80$ it is assumed that the frequency of the incident radiation is much higher than the frequencies of the atom. **I am wondering what happens if the electrons are not assumed to be non-relativistic.**

Comment: its not very legitimate, hence the reason for Compton's claim among others.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus: You are right. I did not formulate my last sentence correctly. Now I changed it.

Comment: Can't you always change reference frames so that the electron is non relativistic and just reuse the same argument?

Comment: @KFGauss: since the electron is acted by the EM field, there is no inertial frame where it is at rest, even if initially it was free.

Answer (score 0):

In classical EM theory, the scattered radiation has the same frequency as the primary wave when the electron oscillates around a central point in space that is at rest. Frequency of the scattered radiation is that of the electron oscillation. (To be more precise, the scattered radiation spectrum does not have exactly delta-like emission line, but it is a series of peaks of narrow but non-zero width, where centers of the peaks are multiples of the primary frequency (harmonics).)

If the central point around which the electron oscillates moves with non-zero velocity, the scattered radiation will be altered by the Doppler effect. Frequency shift will depend on the angle between the direction of propagation of the central point and the direction to the observer. Surprisingly, this angular dependence is the same as in the Compton formula, so this aspect of the Compton scattering can be understood in the classical EM theory. This was first described, as far as I know, in Raman's paper C. V. Raman, *A classical derivation of the Compton effect*, Indian J. Phys. 3 357-369 (1928).

What *isn't explicable* by the classical EM theory alone is why this proposed effective velocity of the central point and thus the frequency shift is related to Planck's constant $h$ and electron mass $m$.